# Convert Mysql Query into Elastic search query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-5

i'm working on elastic search but not expert in making elastic search queries. find my query bellow and if possible to convert into elasticsearch query   then take thanks in advance

```
SELECT
  `currency`.`id`                         AS `cur_id`,
  `currency`.`currency_name`              AS `cur_name`,
  `currency`.`currency_code`              AS `cur_code`,
  `currency`.`currency_slug`              AS `cur_slug`,
  `currency`.`logo`                       AS `cur_logo`,
  `currency`.`added_date`                 AS `cur_added_date`,
  `currency`.`mineable_or_not`            AS `mineable_or_not`,
  `currency`.`market_cap`                 AS `cur_market_cap`,
  `currency`.`circulating_supply`         AS `cur_circulating_supply`,
  `currency`.`max_supply`                 AS `cur_max_supply`,
  `currency`.`total_supply`               AS `cur_total_supply`,
  `currency`.`market_cap`                 AS `ng_cur_market_cap`,
  `currency`.`added_date`                 AS `ng_cur_added_date`,
  `currency`.`circulating_supply`         AS `ng_cur_circulating_supply`,
  `calculations`.`volume_1hour`           AS `cal_volume_1hour`,
  `calculations`.`volume_24hour`          AS `cal_volume_24hour`,
  `calculations`.`volume_168hour`         AS `cal_volume_168hour`,
  `calculations`.`volume_720hour`         AS `cal_volume_720hour`,
  `calculations`.`volume_24hour_btc`      AS `cal_volume_24hour_btc`,
  `calculations`.`current_price`          AS `cal_current_price`,
  `calculations`.`percentage_change`      AS `cal_percentage_change_24h`,
  `calculations`.`percentage_change_1h`   AS `cal_percentage_change_1h`,
  `calculations`.`percentage_change_168h` AS `cal_percentage_change_168h`,
  `calculations`.`volume_24hour`          AS `ng_cal_volume_24hour`,
  `calculations`.`current_price`          AS `ng_cal_current_price`
FROM `currency`
  JOIN `calculations` ON `calculations`.`currency_id` = `currency`.`id`
WHERE `calculations`.`update_status` = 1 AND `currency`.`currency_type` != 3 AND `calculations`.`update_status` = 1 AND `currency`.`status` = 1
ORDER BY `market_cap` DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: There is no join like behavior in elasticsearch. You can query on two indices at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As eliasah commented, there is no join operation in elastic search.

[Joining queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html)

In general you can't really perform joining queries in ES. You can have a parent/child relationship on documents that are under the same index, but that is something I would not opt into. My best advice is to denormalize your data and have each document as 'self-contained' as possible. In this specific example, one possible solution is to store the calculations inside the currency, you would end up with a query like:

```
{
  "_source": ["id", "logo", ..., "calculations.volume_1h","calculations.volume_24h",...],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[   
        {
          "match":{
            "calculations.update_status":1
          }
        },
        {
          "match":{
            "currency_type":3
          }
        },
        {
          "match":{
            "status":1
          }
        }
      ]     
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "market_cap": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
  "size":100
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. can you please also guide me about any tool for elastic-search query generator or any converter for MySQL queries to elastic search queries and any documentation which help me to write elastic queries. Thanks !